# sed doesn't give me the same value two files

Tags: sed

I noticed that sed is not giving me the same output

```
NOD=$(sed -n '/uid=/{s/.*uid=//;p;}' /home/user/config.xml | tail -c +2 |  rev | cut -c6- | rev)
```

file contains:

```
<gateway  ws="ws://1.1.1.23:8333" uid="123B0X3C"/>
```

and result is 123B0X3C, but when i try on another endpoint

```
<gateway  ws="ws://1.1.1.23:8333" uid="1541CCF5"/>
```

result is **1541CCF**

Why?

Idea is to get that number inside uid option without "" and end tag characters

Comment: Why do you `cut -c6-`? Shouldn't it be `cut -c4-`? Anyway, the different behavior is probably due to different amounts of trailing spaces. And your command is much more complex than needed. Try `sed -En 's/.*uid="(.*)".*/\1/p'` or `awk -F\" '/uid=/ {print $4}'`.

Comment: Your question looks like you get unexpected results from these two but completely predictably I get `123B0X3C"/>` and `1541CCF5"/>` respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a single `sed` for this:

```sh
NOD=$(sed -n 's/.*uid="\([^"]*\).*/\1/p' /home/user/config.xml)
```

Here,

- `-n` - suppresses the default line output
- `.*uid="\([^"]*\).*` - finds any text, `uid="` text, then captures any zero or more chars other than a `"` char into Group 1, and then matches the rest of the string
- `\1` - replaces the matched line with Group 1 value
- `p` - `p`rints the result of the successful substitution.

See an [online demo](https://ideone.com/zO7xwZ):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='<gateway  ws="ws://1.1.1.23:8333" uid="123B0X3C"/>'
NOD=$(sed -n 's/.*uid="\([^"]*\).*/\1/p' <<< "$s")
echo "$NOD"
## => 123B0X3C
```

Answer (score 2):

This could be done in simple `awk`. With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code. Simple explanation would be, setting field separator as `uid="` OR `"/>` for all lines, then printing 2nd field of the line.

```
awk -F'uid="|"/>' 'NF>=2{print $2}' Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

this worked

```
NOD=$(sed -n 's/.*uid="\([^"]*\).*/\1/p' /home/user/config.xml)
```

but i am very curious why that didnt work.
When i check leght of variable, it showed me 8, but echo display only 7 characters.
When i move result to file and wc -c it get me  15 and 14 characters (one file and another). I checked blank spaces, but configs are the same.